# How to structure mysql table to avoid extra rows

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

I am maintaining record of expenses an expenses table looks like this

```
Expenses(id,name)
Expenses_data(id,amount,expense_id)
```

Expenses are based on years, lets say 10 years and i am saving it as months, so it would 120 months

If i would have 10 expenses then expenses_data would have 120*10 = 1200 Rows

I want to save it from 1200 rows to 120 rows and data would be like this as i enter in excel

```
id   month    marketing   electricity   bank charges
1    month-1    100          200           300
2    month-2    95.5         5000          100
```

Please suggest if it is possible and how ?

Comment: Search this site for `mysql pivot table` questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably what to stick to the database structure you already have, but use a query to display the data in the format you wish.

If you think about the number of data-points you're storing, there's not much difference between your sought schema and what you already have -- it's still 1200 data-points of expenses.  Having to upgrade your schema each time you add an expense column would be pretty invasive.

Sticking with a query for your excel export would allow the database to understand the concept of expense categories, and updating your export query to include the new category would be much easier than modifying the schema.  The necessary JOINs could even be calculated programmatically by iterating an initial query of "What Expense Categories are known?"